# Updating many rows - One line per group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am trying to figure this out. I have a table with several hundred thousand rows.  Each job # has about 8 rows.  I need to update one column per job # based on the highest value of another column.

[image]

For the job the cntrl_point needs set to 1 where the oper_num is greatest.

```
UPDATE jobroute
SET cntrl_point = 1
SELECT DISTINCT job, cntrl_point, MAX(oper_num) OVER (PARTITION BY job) MAX_Oper_Num
FROM jobroute
WHERE job not like 'J%' AND suffix = 0
```

I assume I am usin the OVER PARTITION incorrectly.  I thought maybe  CURSOR would be more appropriate but I am not sure how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is possible that for same `job` value, have 2 or more identical max values in `oper_num` column ?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` for this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select jr.*, row_number() over (partition by job order by oper_num desc) as seqnum
      from jobroute jr
      where job not like 'J%' AND suffix = 0 
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET cntrl_point = 1
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That updates the first line in the sequence but not the one where oper_num has the greatest value.

Comment: I may have it with this;

Comment: UPDATE a
SET a.cntrl_point = 1
FROM jobroute a
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT job, MAX(oper_num) as MAXOPERNUM
 FROM jobroute
 GROUP BY Job
 --HAVING MAX(
) b ON a.job = b.job and a.oper_num = b.MAXOPERNUM

Comment: @D.Cantrell . . . The `order by` just needs `DESC`.